# Does knowing modular eth roots help in factoring n?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, factoring

Consider $x^e \equiv a\pmod n$, given $n$, $a$, and $e>2$, with $n$ being a composite integer and unknown $x$.

Can a hypothetical function $f(a)=x$, an $eth$ root extractor, be used / adapted to factor $n$, in the same way that the multiplicative order of $x \space modulo\space n$ can be used to factor $n$ like in the classical part of Shor's algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [RSA problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_problem), which you describe, is not known to be equivalent to factoring and there is evidence both ways. In [BV] it is shown that this barrier might be inherent: using a black-box separation technique called *meta-reductions*, they show that certain restricted class of reductions are not possible. On the other hand, it was shown later in [AM] that in the generic ring model (see [JS]), these problems are equivalent. That is, any speed-up in breaking RSA has to exploit the representation of $\mathbb{Z}_N^*$.

You can read about more related works in §1.3 in [AM].

[BV]: Boneh and Venkateshan, [Breaking RSA may not be equivalent to factoring](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0054117), Eurocrypt'98

[AM]: Aggarwal and Maurer, [Breaking RSA Generically Is Equivalent to Factoring](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-01001-9_2), Eurocrypt'09

[JS]: Jager and Schwenk, [On the Analysis of Cryptographic Assumptions in theGeneric Ring Model](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/621.pdf), Asiacrypt'09

Comment: Thank you very much.